# Tag synonym request: message-loop

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I suggest making [messageloop](/questions/tagged/messageloop) a synonym of [message-loop](/questions/tagged/message-loop), because they both mean exactly the same. Because I am not able to do this on stackoverflow, I am asking for this on meta.

Answer (score 1):

Just retag all of the [messageloop](/questions/tagged/messageloop) ones to [message-loop](/questions/tagged/message-loop); you should have the permission to do that.

Well, merged, anyways! =)